# can't edit widgets after moving from subfolder to root

Tags: widgets, dashboard, migration, widget-text

I had some issues with migration: childtheme that was ranamed and working was automatically renamed back + a lot of wrong absolute apps from even older version on site...
Now, after I fixed everithing and changed site url to root, front end is working fine but backend has some UI issues; dropmenues/submenues not working and widget ares are not expanding so widgets can't be edited.
Any suggestions?

EDIT: It seams like only widgets are affected... AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone will ever have these issues, here are some solutions:

1. deactivate WP UI plugin - but if you still want to use it, try to modify

   wp_register_script( 'wpui-script-before', site_url( '?wpui-script=before' ), **___something___** );

to

```
  wp_register_script( 'wpui-script-before', home_url( '?wpui-script=before' ), _____something_____ );
```

in:

/wp-content/plugins/wp-ui/wp-ui.php

/wp-content/plugins/wp-ui/admin/wpUI-options.php

/wp-content/plugins/wp-ui/inc/widgets.php